# Excel - Attach an unique ID to each row based on a cell

Tags: excel

Could someone please help me with something I am trying to do in Excel. Basically, I am trying to attach an unique ID to each row based on a cell.

```
For example:
A         B
0         Apple
0         Apple
0         Pear
0         Strawberry
0         Strawberry
0         Strawberry

Should have the ID's:
A         B
1         Apple
1         Apple
2         Pear
3         Strawberry
3         Strawberry
3         Strawberry
```

I have a list of records of over 5000 rows and I wish to avoid spending time doing this manually. With my basic Excel knowledge, I am struggling to get this done. I have spent a good two hours searching for an answer, but could not find anything that relates to this issue I am facing. It would be great if someone could help me with this. I am looking forward to learning something new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter the following formula in C2 and drag down.

```
=IF(B2=B1;C1;C1+1)
```

This will work as long as your data is sorted by column B, as it is in your example.

Comment: Thank you for coming back to me this fast. I am receiving the error:

When the first character is an equal (=) or minus (-) sign, Excel thinks it's a formula:

=1+1, cell shows: 2

To get around this, type and apostrophe (') first:

=1+1, cell shows: =1+1

Comment: Brilliant! It worked flawlessly. I really appreciate your help. This function will become very handy over time.

Answer (score 0):

In A1 you manually put the value of 1. In A2:

```
= IF( COUNTIF( B$1:B1, B2 ) = 0, MAX( A$1:A1 ) + 1, INDEX( A$1:A1, MATCH( B2, B$1:B1, 0 ) ) )
```

Then you just need to copy this down.